# Why does the HTTP Client Force an Accept-Encoding header

Tags: http, go

Sample Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DisableCompression: true,
        },
    }
    url := "https://google.com"
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    //req.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", "*")
    //req.Header.Del("Accept-Encoding")
    requestDump, err := httputil.DumpRequestOut(req, false)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(requestDump))
    client.Do(req)
}
```

Output:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

With only `req.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", "*"` uncommented:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: *
```

With only `req.Header.Del("Accept-Encoding")` uncommented:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

With both lines uncommented:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Does `DisableCompression` actually do anything to the HTTP Request itself?
According to the godocs:

```
    // DisableCompression, if true, prevents the Transport from
    // requesting compression with an "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
    // request header when the Request contains no existing
    // Accept-Encoding value. If the Transport requests gzip on
    // its own and gets a gzipped response, it's transparently
    // decoded in the Response.Body. However, if the user
    // explicitly requested gzip it is not automatically
    // uncompressed.
```

Comment: Yes, as the docs you've quoted state, it does change the request headers. Have you tested it?

Comment: I've posted the request dumps. It looks like Accept-Encoding is always present. Are you saying it gets removed once the request is actually sent? I tested this in go playground, but in I see similar results in a private project.

Comment: The request you're creating haven't gone through the `Transport` yet, which is where the `DisableCompression` setting exists, so no, any change made by the `Transport` would not be reflected in those dumps.

Comment: is there a way to print what exactly is going over the wire?

Comment: Yes, `DisableCompression` works, but it happens in the transport's roundtrip - after the request is created: https://play.golang.org/p/ZPi-_mfDxI8 (this will timeout on the Playground; try it locally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per document:

> DumpRequestOut is like DumpRequest but for outgoing client requests.
> It **includes any headers that the standard http.Transport adds**, such as User-Agent.

That means it adds "Accept-Encoding: gzip" to the printed wire format.

To test what is actually written to the connection, you need to wrap `Transport.Dial` or `Transport.DialContext` to provide connection that logs written data.

If you are using a transport that supports `httptrace` (which all built-in and "x/http/..." transport implementation supports), you may set up a `WroteHeaderField` callback to inspect written header fields.

If you just need to inspect the headers, however, you can spawn up a `httptest.Server`.

Playground link provided by @EmilePels:
https://play.golang.org/p/ZPi-_mfDxI8

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `Dial`, can you point in the direction of some place I could learn to print out what gets actually written to the wire?

Comment: @ajoseps https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn `net.Conn` is just an interface, you can wrap it like wrapping any interface.

Comment: thank you. I also want to add the `httptrace` package is very useful: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace/. It has a callback function where it lists out the headers that are being sent with their values.

Comment: I've created a separate question to address viewing what gets actually sent out over the wire: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63162180/how-to-view-http-https-interactions-with-http-client-in-go and added a response of my own for `httptrace`/`httputil`. If you have a implementation of wrapping `Transport.DialContext` it would be useful, but the `httptrace` functionality serves me purpose for now.