# How to view HTTP/HTTPS Interactions with HTTP client

Tags: http, go

How do you view what exactly is sent over the wire by a HTTP client and how the connection is configured?

Answer (score 2):

go has packages called `httputil` & `httptrace` that can facilitate viewing the HTTP lifecycle, as well as what is actually sent over the wire: [http-tracing blog post](https://blog.golang.org/http-tracing)
[httptrace go doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace)
[httputil go doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil)

**NOTE** `httputil.DumpRequestOut` is meant for outgoing messages on the client side and `httputil.DumpRequest` are meant for incoming messages on the server side

**NOTE** `httputil.DumpRequestOut` appends the default transport's headers, so if you customize the transport, the changes would not be reflected. See: [Why does the HTTP Client Force an Accept-Encoding header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63160864/why-does-the-http-client-force-an-accept-encoding-header/63161029?noredirect=1#comment111691085_63161029)

Sample Implementation:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptrace"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/textproto"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://www.google.com"
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    requestDump, err := httputil.DumpRequestOut(req, false)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s: REQUEST ERR: %s\n", time.Now(), err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s: REQUEST: \n%s\n", time.Now(), string(requestDump))
    trace := &httptrace.ClientTrace{
        // GetConn is called before a connection is created or
        // retrieved from an idle pool. The hostPort is the
        // "host:port" of the target or proxy. GetConn is called even
        // if there's already an idle cached connection available.
        GetConn: func(hostPort string) {
            fmt.Printf("Get Conn: hostPort: %s\n", hostPort)
        },
        // GotConn is called after a successful connection is
        // obtained. There is no hook for failure to obtain a
        // connection; instead, use the error from
        // Transport.RoundTrip.
        GotConn: func(connInfo httptrace.GotConnInfo) {
            fmt.Printf("Got Conn: connInfo: %+v\n", connInfo)
        },
        // PutIdleConn is called when the connection is returned to
        // the idle pool. If err is nil, the connection was
        // successfully returned to the idle pool. If err is non-nil,
        // it describes why not. PutIdleConn is not called if
        // connection reuse is disabled via Transport.DisableKeepAlives.
        // PutIdleConn is called before the caller's Response.Body.Close
        // call returns.
        // For HTTP/2, this hook is not currently used.
        PutIdleConn: func(err error) {
            fmt.Printf("PutIdlConn: ERR: %s\n", err)
        },
        // GotFirstResponseByte is called when the first byte of the response
        // headers is available.
        GotFirstResponseByte: func() {
            fmt.Println("GotFirstResponseByte")
        },
        // Got100Continue is called if the server replies with a "100
        // Continue" response.
        Got100Continue: func() {
            fmt.Println("Got100Continue")
        },
        // Got1xxResponse is called for each 1xx informational response header
        // returned before the final non-1xx response. Got1xxResponse is called
        // for "100 Continue" responses, even if Got100Continue is also defined.
        // If it returns an error, the client request is aborted with that error value.
        Got1xxResponse: func(code int, header textproto.MIMEHeader) error {
            fmt.Printf("Got1xxResponse: code: %d header: %+v\n", code, header)
            return nil
        },
        // DNSStart is called when a DNS lookup begins.
        DNSStart: func(dnsInfo httptrace.DNSStartInfo) {
            fmt.Printf("DNS Start: dnsInfo: %+v\n", dnsInfo)
        },
        // DNSDone is called when a DNS lookup ends.
        DNSDone: func(dnsInfo httptrace.DNSDoneInfo) {
            fmt.Printf("DNS Done: dnsInfo: %+v\n", dnsInfo)
        },
        // ConnectStart is called when a new connection's Dial begins.
        // If net.Dialer.DualStack (IPv6 "Happy Eyeballs") support is
        // enabled, this may be called multiple times.
        ConnectStart: func(network, addr string) {
            fmt.Printf("Connect Start: Network Addr: %s %s\n", network, addr)
        },
        // ConnectDone is called when a new connection's Dial
        // completes. The provided err indicates whether the
        // connection completedly successfully.
        // If net.Dialer.DualStack ("Happy Eyeballs") support is
        // enabled, this may be called multiple times.
        ConnectDone: func(network, addr string, err error) {
            fmt.Printf("Connect Done: Network Addr: %s %s ERR: %s\n", network, addr, err)
        },
        // TLSHandshakeStart is called when the TLS handshake is started. When
        // connecting to an HTTPS site via an HTTP proxy, the handshake happens
        // after the CONNECT request is processed by the proxy.
        TLSHandshakeStart: func() {
            fmt.Println("TLSHandshakeStart")
        },
        // TLSHandshakeDone is called after the TLS handshake with either the
        // successful handshake's connection state, or a non-nil error on handshake
        // failure.
        TLSHandshakeDone: func(connState tls.ConnectionState, err error) {
            fmt.Printf("TLSHandshakeDone: connState: %+v ERR: %s\n", connState, err)
        },
        // WroteHeaderField is called after the Transport has written
        // each request header. At the time of this call the values
        // might be buffered and not yet written to the network.
        WroteHeaderField: func(key string, value []string) {
            fmt.Printf("WroteHeaderField: key: %s val: %s\n", key, value)
        },
        // WroteHeaders is called after the Transport has written
        // all request headers.
        WroteHeaders: func() {
            fmt.Println("WroteHeaders")
        },
        // Wait100Continue is called if the Request specified
        // "Expect: 100-continue" and the Transport has written the
        // request headers but is waiting for "100 Continue" from the
        // server before writing the request body.
        Wait100Continue: func() {
            fmt.Println("Wait100Continue")
        },
        // WroteRequest is called with the result of writing the
        // request and any body. It may be called multiple times
        // in the case of retried requests.
        WroteRequest: func(info httptrace.WroteRequestInfo) {
            fmt.Printf("WroteRequest: %+v\n", info)
        },
    }
    req = req.WithContext(httptrace.WithClientTrace(req.Context(), trace))

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    fmt.Printf("%s: RESPONSE OBJ: \n%v\n", time.Now(), resp)
}
```

Output:

```
2020-07-29 14:09:53.682167 -0700 PDT m=+0.000769969: REQUEST:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip


Get Conn: hostPort: www.google.com:443
DNS Start: dnsInfo: {Host:www.google.com}
DNS Done: dnsInfo: {Addrs:[{IP:172.217.17.100 Zone:} {IP:2a00:1450:400e:806::2004 Zone:}] Err:<nil> Coalesced:false}
Connect Start: Network Addr: tcp 172.217.17.100:443
Connect Done: Network Addr: tcp 172.217.17.100:443 ERR: %!s(<nil>)
TLSHandshakeStart
TLSHandshakeDone: connState: {Version:772 HandshakeComplete:true DidResume:false CipherSuite:4865 NegotiatedProtocol:h2 NegotiatedProtocolIsMutual:true ServerName: PeerCertificates:[0xc0001d6000 0xc0001d6580] VerifiedChains:[[0xc0001d6000 0xc0001d6580 0xc000278b00]] SignedCertificateTimestamps:[] OCSPResponse:[] ekm:0x1226ae0 TLSUnique:[]} ERR: %!s(<nil>)
Got Conn: connInfo: {Conn:0xc0001a2000 Reused:false WasIdle:false IdleTime:0s}
WroteHeaderField: key: :authority val: [www.google.com]
WroteHeaderField: key: :method val: [GET]
WroteHeaderField: key: :path val: [/]
WroteHeaderField: key: :scheme val: [https]
WroteHeaderField: key: accept-encoding val: [gzip]
WroteHeaderField: key: user-agent val: [Go-http-client/2.0]
WroteHeaders
WroteRequest: {Err:<nil>}
GotFirstResponseByte
2020-07-29 14:09:54.620195 -0700 PDT m=+0.938796345: RESPONSE OBJ:
&{200 OK 200 HTTP/2.0 2 0 map[Alt-Svc:[h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"] Cache-Control:[private, max-age=0] Content-Type:[text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1] Date:[Wed, 29 Jul 2020 21:09:54 GMT] Expires:[-1] P3p:[CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."] Server:[gws] Set-Cookie:[1P_JAR=2020-07-29-21; expires=Fri, 28-Aug-2020 21:09:54 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure NID=204=qnJT-6IGam7-C1fTR8uIkbDPnfV7OwgOGn5-6tGCWLYmeaRMoSKgV1qSRfKGLghNgQVWY9N_o6hUWKm69I5KrdVqIEVVxRy6XSY6F4c1JyTJZZqEMxMlkpznu-PWOn9eAezKBONTxCZgsGZYboEeYZ5-qZBjUvd7BratNIPkTxU; expires=Thu, 28-Jan-2021 21:09:54 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly] X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] X-Xss-Protection:[0]] 0xc00018c1e0 -1 [] false true map[] 0xc000112100 0xc00007c000}
```